# I want to make a simple CalC in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

Here is My code...

```
<html ng-app='CalC'>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/> 
        <script >
            var app = angular.module('CalC',[]);
            app.controller('stoInt',function($scope){
                $scope.parseInt(txt1,10);
                $scope.parseInt(txt2,10);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body  ng-controller="stoInt">
        <div class="panel panel-default" style="height: 200px;width : 200px;margin: 100px;">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter 1st Number" ng-model="txt1" pattern="[0-9]*">
                <br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter 2nd Number" ng-model="txt2" pattern="[0-9]">
            <br><br>
                 <p> Result :: {{txt1+txt2}} </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

o/p Result :: {{txt1+txt2}}.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

There are few mistakes in your code, you need to make parseInt for the scope variable

```
 parseInt($scope.txt1,10);
 parseInt($scope.txt2,10);
```

you can define a function to calculate the sum and return it,

```
  $scope.add = function(){
      return parseInt($scope.txt1) + parseInt($scope.txt2);
  }
```

**DEMO**

```html
    <html ng-app='CalC'>
     <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/> 
      <script >
       var app = angular.module('CalC',[]);
       app.controller('stoInt',function($scope){
          $scope.add = function(){
               return parseInt($scope.txt1) + parseInt($scope.txt2);
             }
       });
      </script>
     </head>
     <body  ng-controller="stoInt">
      <div class="panel panel-default" style="height: 200px;width : 200px;margin: 100px;">
       <div class="panel-body">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter 1st Number" ng-model="txt1" pattern="[0-9]*">
        <br>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter 2nd Number" ng-model="txt2" pattern="[0-9]">
       <br><br>
         <p> Result :: {{add()}} </p>
       </div>
      </div>
      
     </body>
    </html>
```

**Solution 2**

Make the input type as **`number`**,

```
 <div class="panel-body">
 <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter 1st Number" ng-model="txt1" pattern="[0-9]*">
 <br>
 <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter 2nd Number" ng-model="txt2" pattern="[0-9]">
 <br><br>
```

**DEMO**

```html
<html ng-app='CalC'>
     <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/> 
      <script >
       var app = angular.module('CalC',[]);
       app.controller('stoInt',function($scope){          
       });
      </script>
     </head>
     <body  ng-controller="stoInt">
      <div class="panel panel-default" style="height: 200px;width : 200px;margin: 100px;">
       <div class="panel-body">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter 1st Number" ng-model="txt1" pattern="[0-9]*">
        <br>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter 2nd Number" ng-model="txt2" pattern="[0-9]">
       <br><br>
         <p> Result :: {{txt1+txt2}} </p>
       </div>
      </div>
      
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @AlonEitan yes mentioned in answer